# Converting json into csv with jq while only capturing specific keys

Tags: json, csv, jq

This is my first post so apologies if I make mistakes. Consider I have the following json output

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "title": "root logon",
      "login": "61819009",
      "uid": "ajsd879asdjksasda123asd1asd1",
      "password": "OizfD19jC$ySaV$MKpSF",
      "login_url": "http://192.168.0.1/",
      "notes": ""
    },
    {
      "title": "important admin account",
      "login": "admin",
      "uid": "asdjhkasdh89eoajdiuas98ue9aoi",
      "password": "0z5gDUC#Rb354TlLq$KJ",
      "login_url": "",
      "notes": "",
      "folders": [
        {
          "shared_folder": "Department",
          "folder": "Important",
          "option1": false,
          "option2": false
        }
      ]
    }
    {
      "title": "another important admin",
      "login": "admin@domain.com",
      "uid": "asjhe98asiajsijeouiaueiaiu",
      "password": "3pUs@uXEqsxCv7PRkDlJ",
      "login_url": "http://192.168.0.2/",
      "notes": ""
    },
    {
      "title": "switch admin",
      "login": "admin",
      "uid": "asjhe89ausiodjakljskea90ik",
      "password": "hMB!eMsAE8q4aDQuM4LY",
      "login_url": "",
      "notes": "",
      "folders": [
        {
          "shared_folder": "Department2",
          "folder": "network\\switches",
          "option1": false,
          "option2": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

from the list above, I would like to only export title, login, uid, shared folder, and folder fields to csv file. When I run the following command

```
jq --raw-output '.records[] | [.title, .login, .uid, .shared_folder, .folder] | @ tsv > file
```

what I am expecting as a CSV output is

| title | login | uid | shared_folder | folder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| root logon | 61819009 | ajsd879asdjksasda123asd1asd1 |  |  |
| important admin account | admin | asdjhkasdh89eoajdiuas98ue9aoi | Department | Important |
| another important admin | admin@domain.com | asjhe98asiajsijeouiaueiaiu |  |  |
| switch admin | admin | asjhe89ausiodjakljskea90ik | Department2 | network\switches |

instead I'm getting the following CSV output:

| title | login | uid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| root logon | 61819009 | ajsd879asdjksasda123asd1asd1 |
| important admin account | admin | asdjhkasdh89eoajdiuas98ue9aoi |
| another important admin | admin@domain.com | asjhe98asiajsijeouiaueiaiu |
| switch admin | admin | asjhe89ausiodjakljskea90ik |

my goal is to eliminate capturing following fields

- password
- login_url
- notes
- option1
- option2

Comment: The input JSON is not uniformly structured, so it's not clear what you expect. In any case, please follow the [mcve] guidelines, showing the expected output and explaining why that's what you expect.

Comment: @peak I have updated it, is it better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an error in your JSON, [you must add a `,`](https://gist.github.com/aborruso/6db52150565970db10f3f6281fee16a2/revisions).

Once done, the command is [this](https://jqplay.org/s/SHf_cgKAyr)

```
jq --raw-output '.records[] | [.title, .login, .uid, .folders[0].shared_folder,.folders[0].folder] |@tsv'
```

Comment: a late follow up but how would I add it with the headers? for example if we can take the .title, .login .uid .shared_folder and .folders as a header into csv?

Comment: I came up with this but although it works on the that platform, [link](https://jqplay.org/s/C06a9wzSz6), it wouldn't work on my screen. I'm getting `jq: error: RecordTitle/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:`

Comment: @user3594235 please share in gist your input file https://gist.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
.records[]
| [.title, .login, .uid] + ((.folders[]? // null) | [.shared_folder, .folder])
| @tsv
```